# Make all buttons un-clickable for 5 seconds

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an online tick tac toe game (turn based) in **Android Studio**.

Is there a way to make all buttons in my app not work for 5 seconds after clicking a button.I intend to make an object containing this function and call it with an onClick function in my java code so that every time I click on a block, All the buttons (blocks) present in that particular activity becomes un-clickable (but still appear on the screen) for a period of 5 seconds and after that they become normal (clickable).

Comment: Did you consider using a [Progress Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Handler and put all buttons there like this :

```
    final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    final Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btn2.setClickable(false);
            btn3.setClickable(false);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btn2.setClickable(true);
                    btn3.setClickable(true);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After click on button add this

```
TicTacToeButton.setEnabled(false);
TicTacToeButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TicTacToeButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you For the help, But this only makes that particular Button un-clickable. Is there a way to make all the buttons un-clickable ( so that once user clicks on one button, he can't click on any other buttons too for 5 seconds ) ?

Comment: you will have to do by calling each of their ids itseld

Comment: can you please show me its implementation in the code. the button ids are: a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a button (name-disable or anything) and implement click listener
2. put your code like ..

   ```
   button1.setEnabled(false);
   button2.setEnabled(false);
   button3.setEnabled(false);
   ```

after this lines put this method same listener

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

    button1.setEnabled(true);
    button2.setEnabled(true);
    button3.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *onClick()* method, you can disable all buttons using *setClickable(false)*. Note that you need to perform this operation individually for all the buttons. For example,If there are two buttons : button1 and button2 that need to be disabled then do

```
button1.setClickable(false);
button2.setClickable(false);
```

Once you do for all your buttons, use a **Handler** to enable them after 5 seconds

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      enableButtons();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Likewise, in the *enableButtons()* method make *setClickable(true)* for all buttons.